# Overlay Data on Video

Tags: matlab, video

I have collected about thirty seconds of data in Matlab with associated timestamps.

At the same time, I've recorded thirty seconds of webcam data.

I would like to overlay the data onto the video such that each video frame shows the current and previous five seconds' worth of data.

Any ideas?

Comment: We need more info on this...What sort of data is it, and how do you want to visualize it? Overlay how precisely? Must it be overlayed, or is over-under or side-by-side OK? etc. Could you give a bit more detail on what you're trying to do.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis, I have X-Y data where X is a series of timestamps and Y the associated data values (taken at 8000 samples per second). Over-under or side-by-side would be fine. If the time is precise to within a tenth of a second or so, I think that would be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested, but something similar should work:

```
fps_video = 30; % in Hz
fps_data = 8000; % in Hz
duration_video = 30; % in s
number_of_video_frames = fps_video * duration_video;
window_duration = 5; % in s
number_of_datapoints = window_duration * fps_data; % data samples in window_duration seconds

for n = 1:number_of_video_frames 
    subplot(1,2,1);
    imshow(video(n,:,:));
    subplot(1,2,2);
    data_1 = zeros(number_of_datapoints);
    if (n >= (window_duration * fps_video))
        fps_data_1 = (1, (n * fps_data/fps_video) - number_of_datapoints: n * fps_data/fps_video)
        fps_data_2 = ...
    end
    plot(data_1, data_2) % don't know what data_with_timestamps looks like (what is x and y, set data_1 and data_2 accordingly...)
    pause(1/fps_video);
end
```

Comment: In `plot(data_1,data_2)` only `data_1` appears to be defined, but I understand what you're getting at. Thanks :-)